# How do I delete a release from Google Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I made a necessary update to my game while the first bundle that I uploaded is still in review. How do I delete the previous release, because I don't want to waste time with 2 releases being reviewed and published? This is for my graduation project and I'm running very low on time so any help is much much appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't delete a release.
As your previous one is still at review stage, upload a new release. Once there's a new release avaiable for review, they won't review the older one.

Comment: even after review I never managed to find a way to delete the old release. I guess I will have to carry old releases for the rest of my life

Comment: @MwBakker You're married to releases.

Comment: @MwBakker were you able to release only one of the two releases after they were approved?

Comment: @LuckyStarr you'll be able to release only the last version you sent to review.

Answer (score 0):

Once a release has been created there is no way to discard or modify it. Moreover, you can't choose which release to send for review; so if you create a new release with the intent of substituting the previous one, you have to send both to review. After they pass the review you must release both.

This information comes from a direct experience and from the information the support gave me. These are the relevant parts of the communication with the support:

> [ME] I have two releases in status "Ready to send for review". Is it
> possible to discard one of the two?
>
> [SUPPORT] Unfortunately, it is not
> possible to discard the changes that are ready to be send for a
> review.
>
> [ME] ok, once they are been successfully reviewed, can I
> decide to publish only one of them?
>
> [SUPPORT] All changes that are
> reviewed will automatically be released.